# removing keys and values from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I'm relatively new to programming and I'm quite stuck.

I have a dictionary like this below. I want to say like
`n = "a"`
then I want to remove every variable `n` from the dictionary.

Then I want to remove every letter `a` that is in this nested dictionary below. I know how to remove stuff from dictionaries to a tiny extent, but I'm quite confused right now as I don't know how to do it with a nested dictionary. In this case, there's a key and then a value but inside the value is another dictionary with other keys and values. I have implemented for loops etc. to try and do what I want to do but the solution I get isn't what I'm looking for.

Thank you:)

```
{'b': {'a': 7, 'c': 10, 'd': 15}, 'a': {'b': 7, 'c': 9, 'f': 14}, 'c': {'a': 9, 'b': 10, 'd': 11, 'f': 2}, 'f': {'a': 14, 'c': 2, 'e': 9}, 'd': {'b': 15, 'c': 11, 'e': 6}, 'e': {'d': 6, 'f': 9}}

dic = {'b': {'a': 7, 'c': 10, 'd': 15}, 'a': {'b': 7, 'c': 9, 'f': 14}, 'c': {'a': 9, 'b': 10, 'd': 11, 'f': 2}, 'f': {'a': 14, 'c': 2, 'e': 9}, 'd': {'b': 15, 'c': 11, 'e': 6}, 'e': {'d': 6, 'f': 9}}
```

This is what I have so far, but it's just removing the first b which is a key, how do i access the b's inside the nested dictionary

```
n = "b"

del dic[n]

print(dic)
```

and whenever I do something like :

```
dic = {'b': {'a': 7, 'c': 10, 'd': 15}, 'a': {'b': 7, 'c': 9, 'f': 14}, 'c': {'a': 9, 'b': 10, 'd': 11, 'f': 2}, 'f': {'a': 14, 'c': 2, 'e': 9}, 'd': {'b': 15, 'c': 11, 'e': 6}, 'e': {'d': 6, 'f': 9}}
```

and whenever I do something like:

```
n = "b"

for k in dic.keys():
    if k == n:
        del dic[k]
```

it comes up in the terminal that RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: sorry didnt realise i had to include my code I will next time sorry @Prune

Comment: what is the expected output from the code above?

Comment: Why not do it *this* time?
Go through the intro tour (as you should have done already), and follow the posting guidelines.  Give us the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and we can help.

Comment: @Onyambu my code right now just removes n="b" , and right now I just know how to get the key one away, I dont know how to access that value inside that nested dictionary that contains values and dictionarys too

Answer (score 1):

You could write a recursive function:

```
def delete_key(k, dic):
  if k in dic:
      del dic[k]
  for val in dic.values():
    if isinstance(val, dict):
       delete_key(k, val)
  return dic

d = {'b': {'a': 7, 'c': 10, 'd': 15}, 'a': {'b': 7, 'c': 9, 'f': 14}, 'c': {'a': 9, 'b': 10, 'd': 11, 'f': 2}, 'f': {'a': 14, 'c': 2, 'e': 9}, 'd': {'b': 15, 'c': 11, 'e': 6}, 'e': {'d': 6, 'f': 9}}

delete_key('b', d)

{'a': {'c': 9, 'f': 14},
 'c': {'a': 9, 'd': 11, 'f': 2},
 'd': {'c': 11, 'e': 6},
 'e': {'d': 6, 'f': 9},
 'f': {'a': 14, 'c': 2, 'e': 9}}
```

Comment: A few minor improvements: You can just do `if k in dic` because it's the same as `if k in dic.keys()`. For the loop, `for val in dic.values()` would make more sense, as you're not using `key`. Also, there's no reason to `return dic`.

Comment: hi thank you for your help:) thats exactly what i wanted but for the recursive part, it doesn't work with my code becuase my delete_key function only has to take in the variable k i've tried alternating it for my code but it keeps saying recursion dept exceeded

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to convert the dictionary to a matrix, you can do this as follows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

dictionary = {
    'b': {'a': 7, 'c': 10, 'd': 15},
    'a': {'b': 7, 'c': 9, 'f': 14},
    'c': {'a': 9, 'b': 10, 'd': 11, 'f': 2},
    'f': {'a': 14, 'c': 2, 'e': 9},
    'd': {'b': 15, 'c': 11, 'e': 6},
    'e': {'d': 6, 'f': 9}
}


keys_removed = [dictionary.get(i) for i in dictionary]

dictvectorizer = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
matrix = dictvectorizer.fit_transform(keys_removed)
```

This will provide the following output:

```
[[ 7.  0. 10. 15.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  7.  9.  0.  0. 14.]
 [ 9. 10.  0. 11.  0.  2.]
 [14.  0.  2.  0.  9.  0.]
 [ 0. 15. 11.  0.  6.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  6.  0.  9.]]
```

With matrix indices corresponding to the inner key values (a to f), which is why the matrix has zeroes where a value does not exist at a specific key.

Alternatively, if you just want to get rid of the main keys, you simply need to use `keys_removed = [dictionary.get(i) for i in dictionary]` and convert it from a list.
This will give you the following:

```
[{'a': 7, 'c': 10, 'd': 15}, {'b': 7, 'c': 9, 'f': 14}, {'a': 9, 'b': 10, 'd': 11, 'f': 2}, {'a': 14, 'c': 2, 'e': 9}, {'b': 15, 'c': 11, 'e': 6}, {'d': 6, 'f': 9}]
```

**EDIT**

If you want to delete certain keys and their corresponding entries, you could do something like this:

```
def delete_key(keys: list):

    dictionary = {
        'b': {'a': 7, 'c': 10, 'd': 15},
        'a': {'b': 7, 'c': 9, 'f': 14},
        'c': {'a': 9, 'b': 10, 'd': 11, 'f': 2},
        'f': {'a': 14, 'c': 2, 'e': 9},
        'd': {'b': 15, 'c': 11, 'e': 6},
        'e': {'d': 6, 'f': 9}
    }

    
    for i in keys:
        dictionary.pop(i)
        
    return dictionary
    
print (delete_key(keys=['a', 'c']))
```

This takes a list of keys that you want to delete and returns a new dictionary without them. The above case outputs:

```
{'b': {'a': 7, 'c': 10, 'd': 15}, 'f': {'a': 14, 'c': 2, 'e': 9}, 'd': {'b': 15, 'c': 11, 'e': 6}, 'e': {'d': 6, 'f': 9}}
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your reply:) I appreciate it so much thank you. But what i'm trying to get my code to do is delete all instances of a letter that i want deleted from the dictionary. I've tried up above some ways but I'm relatively new to programming and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Thank you

Comment: You notice that your dictionary still contains some values keys 'a' . You should remove these as well.

Comment: I have just read the most recent edit to the question and I do agree. Initially there was no reference to which keys should be removed. Adding another answer now. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

According to your recent clarifications, this should work:

```
def delete_key(outer_keys: list, inner_keys: list):

    dictionary = {
        'b': {'a': 7, 'c': 10, 'd': 15},
        'a': {'b': 7, 'c': 9, 'f': 14},
        'c': {'a': 9, 'b': 10, 'd': 11, 'f': 2},
        'f': {'a': 14, 'c': 2, 'e': 9},
        'd': {'b': 15, 'c': 11, 'e': 6},
        'e': {'d': 6, 'f': 9}
    }

    
    for i in outer_keys:
        dictionary.pop(i)
        
    for i in dictionary:
        for j in inner_keys:
            if j in dictionary[i]:
                dictionary[i].pop(j)
        
    return dictionary
    
print (delete_key(outer_keys=[], inner_keys=['a']))
```

The function works as follows:

- It allows you to specify which keys (and corresponding entries) you want removed. You simply list which in either `outer_keys` or `inner_keys`, the latter being the deepest keys in the nested dictionary.
- These have to be defined as a list of the key names and can be empty if you want to only remove the keys from the inner or outer.

The above example will output the following:

```
{'b': {'c': 10, 'd': 15}, 'a': {'b': 7, 'c': 9, 'f': 14}, 'c': {'b': 10, 'd': 11, 'f': 2}, 'f': {'c': 2, 'e': 9}, 'd': {'b': 15, 'c': 11, 'e': 6}, 'e': {'d': 6, 'f': 9}}
```

You will notice that all of the inner 'a' keys have been removed. The operation can be done using fewer loops, but this should illustrate the process well enough.